# broadcast live video from android with ffmpeg source code

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, live

Any suggestion for live stream for android.

In my app i need to broadcast live video from android on a web,some app like Qik, Justin.tv, Ustream.tv and Bambuser.
it is developed under ffmpeg, 
anyone would help if there is any open source project like this,or anyone had already done it
please tell me the project name or send me a copy of the code.

Email:liangyingshuang@gmail.com

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Bambuser have opened source their version of ffmpeg that compiles on the Android. That should get you started.

see: http://bambuser.com/opensource

Comment: Thanks,i had already compiled the ffmpeg downloaded from qik,but i do not know how to invoke the function of ffmpeg, can you provide some examples,

Comment: @keven have a look at ffmpeg.c file which is in your ffmpeg directory..This is a good example of how to use ffmpeg...

Answer (score 1):

Best thing is `SpyDroid` http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/

It works the same as Qik